# Rasterising shapefile in Python?

Tags: python, software-recommendations, rasterization, geocube

I am trying to rasterize a shapefile with Python using ogr, but if you know to do with other libraries as fiona, I am interested in too.

I use the shapefile in the following website: https://www.hydrosheds.org/page/hydrolakes (Lake polygon).
I try to get a raster of 0.5° resolution and in lat/lon projection. I want to create a matrice `M` where `M(i,j)` correspond to lake fraction. In my shapefile the polygons are lakes.

I see people using the function `gdal.RasterizeLayer(target_ds, [1], source_layer, burn_values=[0])` and I don't success to use it.

Can you give me tips?

I just success to get a raster with undefined values.

EDIT

I try the method of snowman2.
But finally with a friend that have the costum to do it R. I follow his algorithm in python with ogr and I sucess to get something precise.

I will put the code within the day.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Thank you for taking the Tour. Please [edit] the question to specify the exact software in use, what you have attempted, and what is wrong with the result. Tutorial reference requests are likely to be closed as *opinion-based*.

Comment: In fact, the libraries can be fiona, ogr, shapely or others. 
In this moment, I just try with the same template than the code Convert an OGR File to a Raster  in the page:
https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/raster_layers.html
and when i change a little bit to adapt to my data, I had only a matrice nul.
Do I use the function gdal.RasterizeLayer(target_ds, [1], source_layer, burn_values=[0]) or another one

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to make clarifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using geocube for this: https://corteva.github.io/geocube/stable/examples/grid_to_vector_map.html

It wraps rasterio & geopandas/fiona.

Here is an example of how to rasterize the shapefile & calculate the lake fraction:

```py
import geopandas
import numpy
from geocube.api.core import make_geocube
from rasterio.enums import Resampling

gpd = geopandas.read_file("hydrolakes/hydrolakes_subset.gpkg")
gpd["exists"] = 1

cube = make_geocube(
    vector_data=gpd,
    measurements=["exists"],
    resolution=(0.05, -0.05),
    fill=numpy.nan,
).fillna(0)

upsampled = cube.rio.reproject(cube.rio.crs, resolution=0.5, resampling=Resampling.average)

upsampled.exists.rio.to_raster("lake_fraction.tif")
```

Results:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, axes = plt.subplots()

upsampled.where(upsampled!=0).exists.plot(ax=axes)
cube.where(cube!=0).exists.plot(ax=axes)
```

[image: Lake fraction]

The small blue squares are the originally rasterized lakes. The larger squares are the resampled raster with the fraction of the cell that has lakes in it.

Comment: Thanks for this method. I am not so good to download the python libraries when they are not on conda. Geocube is not inside. At the moment i follow your method, but it is very time cunsumming.
But really thanks to try  to help me :)

Comment: You can install geocube with conda using the conda-forge channel. `conda install -c conda-forge geocube`.

Comment: Also, can adjust the initial resolution depending on the speed you want in processing the data and how accurate you need the lake fraction to be.

Comment: Perfect I success to download it.